# How to time condition at compile time

Tags: templates, c++11, gcc, visual-studio-2013, clang

I search for a way to print a message or break a compile run if a headerfile is expired, something like:

```
#ifndef somemagic(__DATE__ , "2014")
#pragma message("ALARM! Someone should check this file!")
#endif
```

or is there some new template magic?

To be more specific. I got no way to change the compiler chain. The solution has to be part of the source code. A compiler switch or even add a define in a makefile is not an option.

**Note:**
It is a technical question, which (IMHO) deservers a technical answer. Even if may not fit in all situation, there are reasons where such a technic may be handy.

Comment: I'm not sure it is a good thing to do. If you really wanted that with GCC, you could extend it using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)

Comment: But I really think you are wrong in wanting this. Someone might want in 2016 to compile the source code at version of september 11th, 2014, with legitimate reasons. At that time, you might not even work in the same place!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fact that `__DATE__` expands to a string literal, and string literals are constant expressions:

```
static_assert(
  ( 1000 * (__DATE__[7] - '0')
   + 100 * (__DATE__[8] - '0')
   +  10 * (__DATE__[9] - '0')
   +       (__DATE__[10] - '0')
  ) != 2014, "It's 2014!"
);
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://ideone.com/pRTy6S)</kbd>

Comment: That's nearly a hit :-) Unfortunately VS2013 gives me a error C2057 "expected constant expression". Didn't checked it with clang yet.

Comment: @MartinSchlott [Works with clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8414ca0e1861c7e). I'd suspect a VS2013 bug - they don't even implement `constexpr` yet, so their general constant expression support might be limited as well.

Comment: Looks like you are right. static_assert cannot evaluate any constant string. Looks clearly like a bug to me too.

Comment: @MartinSchlott GCC and Clang agree with each other, and reading C++11 5.19 (Constant expressions), I couldn't find anything to prohibit string literal indexing in constant expressions. So I am inclined to believe this to be an issue of VS non-conformance.

Comment: Uups. I forgot to add Visual Studio 2013 to my comment before. XCode (Clang) works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way might be to change your *build machinery* to compile with e.g. `-DCURRENT_BUILD_YEAR=2014`. On Linux with a `Makefile` you could add into it:

```
 CPPFLAGS += -DCURRENT_BUILD_YEAR=$(shell date +%Y)
```

Then code something like

```
 #if CURRENT_BUILD_YEAR > 2014
 #error someone should look at this
 #endif
```

However, as I commented, it is a bad thing to do IMHO. Maybe considering a version control hook could be more relevant.

If you insist on doing it in the compiler (which I believe is the wrong approach), with GCC consider extending it with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)

<sup>I believe you want a technical only solution to a social or management issue, and this is always the wrong thing to do!</sup>

BTW, being inspired by [Angew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26465905/841108), you might perhaps try:

```
#define CURRENT_BUILD_YEAR   (1000 * (__DATE__[7] - '0')   \
                               + 100 * (__DATE__[8] - '0') \
                               +  10 * (__DATE__[9] - '0') \
                               +       (__DATE__[10] - '0'))
```

but I guess it probably would not work, because I don't think that the preprocessor
is expected to know about `[]` index at compile time.

Comment: "change your build machinery" is the problem here. The header is part of a process I have no way to change. I extended my question by this.

Comment: I meant changing your Makefile.

Comment: Nice, but nope. As you already mentioned the preprocessor does not like a string after #if. Tried it with XCode (Clang) and VS2013. But thx.